# Haystack not displaying results

Tags: django, django-haystack, whoosh

I search for terms in the model and it didnt bring 'No result found'.I checked the source code of the page and it claerly shows it is seeing something in the search but its not displaying it in browser

```
<h3>Results</h3>

                <p>
                    <a href=""></a>
                </p>
```

This is my model:

```
class Feed(models.Model):
    text=models.TextField(blank=False,max_length=5000)
    auth=models.ForeignKey(Authority,blank=False)
```

## search-indexes.py

```
class FeedIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True,)
    text1 = indexes.CharField(model_attr='text')
    auth = indexes.CharField(model_attr='auth')

    def get_model(self):
        return Feed

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

## feed_text.txt

```
{{ object.text }}
{{ object.auth.name }}
```

## search.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Search</h2>

    <form method="get" action=".">
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Search">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        {% if query %}
            <h3>Results</h3>

            {% for result in page.object_list %}
                <p>
                    <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{result.object.text}}</a>
                </p>
            {% empty %}
                <p>No results found.</p>
            {% endfor %}

            {% if page.has_previous or page.has_next %}
                <div>
                    {% if page.has_previous %}<a href="?q={{ query }}&amp;page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">{% endif %}&laquo; Previous{% if page.has_previous %}</a>{% endif %}
                    |
                    {% if page.has_next %}<a href="?q={{ query }}&amp;page={{ page.next_page_number }}">{% endif %}Next &raquo;{% if page.has_next %}</a>{% endif %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
            {# Show some example queries to run, maybe query syntax, something else? #}
        {% endif %}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Kindly help me out

Comment: did you run ./manage.py createindex   ?

Comment: @PrashantGaur You mean ./manage.py rebuild_index?.Yes,I have done it